# C# Datetime insert SQL Server value with microseconds precise

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I'm using .Net Core 2.2 with Entity Framework. I need to insert some data into SQL Server.

In C# I use `DateTime` datatype, and in SQL Server I use `datetime2(6)` - with the default value is: **(sysdatetime())**.

For example my object looks like:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; } 
}
```

If I leave the CreatedTime null while creating the object and leave it for SQL Server to use the default (sysdatetime()), I will get something like: **2020-05-19 09:31:12.383593** in the database.

As I understand the DateTime datatype itself already having the microseconds precise, however, If I set a value for that CreatedTime property, for example:

```
obj.CreatedTime = DateTime.Now.AddTicks(123);
Console.WriteLine(obj.CreatedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));
```

I can see the value in the console, it would be **2020-08-18 07:42:52.131102** . But when insert that obj through EntityFramwork the value in the Database will be just at milliseconds: **2020-08-18 07:42:52.131000** . It looks like EntityFramework somehow only passing DateTime at milliseconds precise?

Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: You need to use the DateTime2 datetype `modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));` or `modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntiity>().Property(f => f.SomeDate).HasColumnType("datetime2");`

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: It's worth you knowing that `DateTime` in SQL isn't super precise (yup I was shocked when I first found this out!), have a look at `DateTime2` see https://database.guide/datetime-vs-datetime2-in-sql-server-whats-the-difference/

Comment: Also you may want to consider storing the value as ticks (i.e. as a number rather than date in SQL) if you want extra precision

Comment: I would also adivse you to save UTC times in your DB. Because of localization issues.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere, EF must be inferring the SQL data type, and it gets it wrong. You might want to use data annotations: `[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2(6)")]` (even though [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-data-types) claims that the default mapping for DateTime when targeting SQL Server is DateTime2(7))

Comment: @d219 _"consider storing the value as ticks"_ - no, don't try to outsmart the database, use the appropriate data types. By converting it to a number, you disable all date functions in both database and code, and it requires unnecessary mapping. Also, timezones.

Comment: @user743414 UTC isn't the answer to everything. If the system is designed to be a local system, there's no point of converting to UTC, for instance.

Comment: What version of Sql Server is this?

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's a valid point. Just wanted to note possible issues and how to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I really appreciate your help ! @Michael Randall thank you so much that solved my problem! Can you post it as an answer I'll mark it the correct answer!

Comment: @CodeCaster - yes but if he needs a value that is more precise than the DB will hold in a datetime format it's worth thinking about (maybe he doesn't here though, if DateTime2 will cover it then that's fine, just something I've had to at least consider before)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to force EF to use the SQL Server `DateTime2(7)` max/default datatype with 100ns precision (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.0000000`), you can do this several ways

**Globally**

```
modelBuilder
  .Properties<DateTime>()
  .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```

**Explicitly**

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<SomeEntiity>()
  .Property(f => f.SomeDate)
  .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

**Or via Attributes**

```
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2(7)")]
```